# Is it possible to refer a column in a view as foreign key (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, view

CREATE VIEW public.productView AS
    SELECT *
    FROM dup.products;

CREATE TABLE public.dep_prodView (
    order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    product_no integer REFERENCES public.productView,
    quantity integer
);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VIEW`s do not represent data (there is exception though: materialized views).

View is a stored object that represents a query, so you cannot create a `FOREIGN CONSTRAINT` to it, since it does not hold any data itself.